# SQL Output Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

While I consider this to be a fairly simply query, apparently there is "Incorrect syntax near 'output'".  Other online resources have not been helpful in debugging this problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
DECLARE @changes TABLE (client_id_copy INT, client_id INT);

UPDATE gmdev.contacts 
SET client_id_copy=a.client_id
FROM gmdev.profile a, gmdev.contacts b
output client_id_copy, inserted.client_id into @changes
WHERE a.custid=b.custid
and NOT(Client_ID_copy > '')
and b.custid in
(select custid from gmdev.profile where custtype='EZ2');
```

**Edit:**

The following suggestion DOES NOT WORK:

```
DECLARE @changes TABLE (client_id_copy INT, client_id INT);

UPDATE gmdev.contacts 
SET client_id_copy=a.client_id
OUTPUT client_id_copy, inserted.client_id into @changes
FROM gmdev.profile a, gmdev.contacts b
WHERE a.custid=b.custid
and NOT(Client_ID_copy > '')
and b.custid in
(select custid from gmdev.profile where custtype='EZ2');
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly..??

Comment: just put the output clause one line above

Comment: Serge is right. See BOL syntax definition: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: @HiteshMistry It's just a basic query to fix some data, but it has to spit out what it changed for logging purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In come cases, **lazy system administrators** may not upgrade to an **up-to-date version of SQL**.

First, make sure the `OUTPUT` keyword is supported by running `Select @@version;`  This will return a cell like so:

```
Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2282 (Intel X86) 
Dec 30 2008 02:22:41 
Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.0 (Build 2195: Service Pack 4)
```

If the result is **older than `Microsoft SQL Server  2005`** then `OUTPUT` is not supported!

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @changes TABLE (client_id_copy INT, client_id INT);

UPDATE gmdev.contacts 
SET client_id_copy=a.client_id
output inserted.client_id_copy, inserted.client_id into @changes
FROM gmdev.profile a, gmdev.contacts b
WHERE a.custid=b.custid
and NOT(Client_ID_copy > '') -- Weird...
and b.custid in
(select custid from gmdev.profile where custtype='EZ2');
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem.  I am still getting the "Incorrect syntax" error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: (+inserted) output inserted.client_id_copy, inserted.client_id into @changes ?

Comment: No, that does not work, but it also isn't the desired result.  I want to get the OLD value of client_id_copy as well as the value it has been replaced by.

Comment: @don4of4 - just seen your most recent comment and updated my answer. If you want the OLD value, you have to reference `deleted` rather than `inserted`.

Comment: then it's the deleted table, I can't guess that ^^

Answer (score 3):

**We** don't have your tables and data, so it's a bit tricky for us to *debug* any issues, but the following does compile and run:

```
create table contacts (client_id_copy int,custid int,client_id int)
create table profile(custid int,client_id int,custtype varchar(10))
DECLARE @changes TABLE (client_id_copy INT, client_id INT);

UPDATE contacts 
SET client_id_copy=a.client_id
OUTPUT deleted.client_id_copy,inserted.client_id into @changes
FROM profile a, contacts b
WHERE a.custid=b.custid
and NOT(Client_ID_copy > '')
and b.custid in
(select custid from profile where custtype='EZ2');

select * from @changes
```

As I say though, I don't know if its correct because we don't know what your tables look like (I've just made up some definitions). Every column listed in the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) has to include the relevant table name or alias (or `inserted` or `deleted`):

```
<column_name> ::=
   { DELETED | INSERTED | from_table_name } . { * | column_name }
   | $action
```

And note that `{ DELETED | INSERTED | from_table_name }` isn't marked as optional, so that's why `OUTPUT client_id_copy,` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE #contacts(client_id_copy INT NULL, custid INT NULL);
CREATE TABLE #profile(client_id INT NULL, custid INT NULL);

DECLARE @changes TABLE (client_id_copy INT, client_id INT);

UPDATE 
    #contacts 
SET 
    client_id_copy=a.client_id
OUTPUT 
    inserted.client_id_copy AS client_id_copy, 
    a.client_id AS client_id
    INTO @changes
FROM 
    #contacts AS b
    INNER JOIN #profile AS a ON
        a.custid=b.custid

DROP TABLE #contacts;
DROP TABLE #profile;
```